# ¿Cómo se maneja el paso por referencia y el paso por valor al pasar argumentos a funciones?

Tags: javascript

Algunas veces me encuentro en situaciones mientras escribo donde necesito entender cómo JavaScript maneja el paso por referencia y el paso por valor al pasar argumentos a funciones. Sé que en algunos casos, los objetos se pasan por referencia, mientras que los tipos primitivos se pasan por valor. Quisiera obtener una explicación detallada sobre cómo funcionan ambos enfoques en JavaScript y cómo puedo evitar problemas comunes al lidiar con este concepto.

Si alguien pudiera proporcionar ejemplos y casos de uso en los que este comportamiento pueda generar problemas, estaría muy agradecido. Además, si existen buenas prácticas para mitigar estos problemas, sería útil conocerlas.

Gracias por adelantado por cualquier aporte o consejo sobre este tema c:

Answer (score 0):

Aquí tienes algunos ejemplos

```
    // Ejemplo de paso por referencia
function modificarArray(arr) {
  arr.push("Nuevo elemento");
}

const miArray = ["Hola", "Mundo"];
modificarArray(miArray);
console.log(miArray); // Imprimirá ["Hola", "Mundo", "Nuevo elemento"]

// Ejemplo de paso por valor
function modificarNumero(num) {
  num = 100;
}

let miNumero = 42;
modificarNumero(miNumero);
console.log(miNumero); // Imprimirá 42
```